# Javascript disable enter on form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-control

I am trying to disable submitting a form when the user presses enter on input fields, but I can't seem to get anything to work. The latest script I've tried was adding this to the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).keydown(function(event){
            if(event.target.tagName != 'INPUT') {
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am not receiving any errors in the console so I can't tell if something is conflicting.

Comment: You want `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're capturing the event in the window, so `preventDefault()` isn't going to do what you want it to. you need to capture it from the form so you can prevent its default submit action

Try:

```
$('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You should replace the delegation of 'keyup keypress' event with 'submit', else that piece of code is going to execute on everytime user interact with the form.

Comment: I disagree. I think it makes more sense to check on every keypress. All this is checking is if the key code is 13, so it's not like running it each time is a lot of overhead

Comment: the condition keyCode === 13 is checked inside the function. That means , irrespect what key is pressed, the function would always be invoked.

Comment: right, I'm not saying it's not going to run. I'm just saying all it's gonna do is check the key code and move on. it's a single comparison calculation so it's almost negligible

Comment: Discarding all `'submit'` events would prevent the form from being submitted by any means. If this is acceptable (i.e. if the OP intends to collect form data and submit it via AJAX), then it's both cleaner and more performant than listening to key events.

Comment: Also, `return false;` from a jQuery handler is equivalent to `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault()`, so it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for all your help but that didn't seem to work. Maybe I have my field setup incorrectly? '<form><input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Address, Listing ID, Agent Name" /></form>'

Basically, this is a live search field so when the user enters information, it displays results below so this should not be submitting at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event capturing](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) for that.

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
        if(event.target.tagName != 'INPUT') {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, true);
```